# Creating maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: maven, myeclipse

The problem occurred when I created a maven project with myeclipse9, I don't know what's wrong. Does anybody know how to solve it? Thanks.

`'Creating maven-archetype-webapp' has encountered a problem.

Failed to create project.`

Comment: There isn't much information to go on. Are there more details of the error? How were you trying to create the project?

Comment: just use the File->New->Other->Maven Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a problem identified in MyEclipse 9 and fixed in MyEclipse 10. If you install release 10 or release 2013, you shouldn't get the problem. MyEclipse licenses are time based, not release based, so you can install any release under the license.